# Отображении диалога на экране

Tags: android, jdialog

При отображении диалога `alertDialog.show();` окно диалога выводится по средине экрана, и появляется панель навигации андроида. Вопрос 1 - как сделать так, что бы окно диалога выводилось в указанном месте а не посредине? Вопрос 2 - как сделать так, что бы при выводе диалога на экран, панель навигации андроида не появлялась? P.S. Второй вопрос можно решить путем замены диалога на активность. Как это сделать я знаю, хотелось бы использовать именно диалог.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вам советовал заменить alertDialog на DialogFragment,во-первых потому, что alertDialog вещь немного устаревшая и имеющая ряд проблем, а во-вторых я полагаю что проблему № 2 он решит.
 Ну а размещение диалога можно изменить при ** onCreateView** создав

Я например делал так:

```
 public class CustomDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams p = getDialog().getWindow().getAttributes();
        p.y = (int) yPos;               
        p.width=WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
        getDialog().getWindow().setAttributes(p);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, не совсем мой случай, но очень помогло.